# How to send struct data as function input on Remix or web3 call?

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, web3.py

I've created a function which gets a struct which contains int+struct. 
Now when I want to test it, what data should I send for example on Remix:

here's the code, got from another SO question on - [How to send an array of structs as arguments](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70525/how-can-i-send-array-of-structs-as-arguments)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract ExchangeContract {
  enum CurrencyType { USD, TWOKEY, BTC, ETH, DAI, USDT, TUSD, EUR, JPY, GBP}

  mapping(uint256 => CurrencyPrice) public priceByCurrencyType;

  struct Price{
    uint price;
    uint decimals;
  }

  struct CurrencyPrice{
    uint currencyInt;
    Price price;
  }

  function updatePrices(CurrencyPrice[] memory _array) public {
    for(uint i=0; i<_array.length; i++){
      priceByCurrencyType[_array[0].currencyInt].price=_array[i].price;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I want to interact with that function from Remix - is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The struct used as the parameter type in your `updatePrices` has a particularity, it contains a member which type is another struct. We will come back to that later, for now let's look how it goes with a "simple" struct.

```js
contract Contract {

  struct Simple {
      int a;
      int b;
  }

  Simple[] public array;

  function add(Simple[] memory _array) public {
    for(uint i=0; i<_array.length; i++){
        array.push(_array[i]);
    } 
  }

}
```

You can see it's rather simple. **On Remix**, if you want to call `add`, it's simple too. You just create an array, like you would for any other type, and then add "sub-arrays" which will represent each struct.

Here's an example :

```
[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

You are adding two structs. The first one contains `1`and `2`, which will be respectively assigned to the `a` and `b` members of the struct, and same thing for the second one which has `3`and `4`.

### Now, back to your contract.

Logically, we would call `updatePrices` with the following input `[[5,[2,2]]]`. It's an array of length `1`, with `5` being the `currencyInt` member and `[2,2]` the corresponding values for the `Price` struct.

**It's not possible on remix.ethereum.org for now, it won't work.**

However, it's implemented on [alpha remix](http://remix-alpha.ethereum.org), and if you used the input above, it will work fine.

[image]

### Regarding your contract itself

I think there is an error on this line

```js
priceByCurrencyType[_array[0].currencyInt].price=_array[i].price;
                           ^
```

You probably intended to do `_array[i]`.